Getting an Internal Server Error when I try to edit my App Script
I have been working on a Google Sheet linked to a Google Form. I created a app script and tested it to work fine.  Then I closed the App script editor and cannot get it to open again.  Everytime I try to invoke the App script editor it gives me a 500 error.
If I try doing so with a new google sheet, it tries to open the script editor but tells me "Failed to create a script for my user"
I tried rebooting my computer, loging off from Google and a fresh login to no avail.

It seems tht this issue has already been confirmed by Google side. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/342510512 https://support.cloud.google.com/portal/system-status?product=WORKSPACE&product_group=GOOGLE_WORKSPACE

This incident was already ackowledged in the Google Workspace Status Dashboard
From the Specific incident report

Summary:
Google Drive users are unable to load Apps Script UI.
Description:
We are experiencing an issue with Google Drive beginning on Friday, 2024-05-24 16:20 US/Pacific.
Our engineering team has identified a mitigation strategy and is currently rolling it out for all impacted users.
We will provide an update by Friday, 2024-05-24 21:00 US/Pacific with current details.
We apologize to all who are affected by the disruption.
Customer Symptoms:
Customers may not be able to load Drive UI, they would encounter error messages while trying to do so. . This issue may also impact users trying to access Apps Script UI.
Workaround:
None at this time.

Related

Post in the official Google Docs Editors Community: Unable to Use Apps Script Editor - Receiving 500 Error


The problem is fixed on the two Workspace accounts I used yesterday.
